# Should the tooltip that appears when voting up a question be modified?

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface

It currently reads: This question shows **research effort**; it is useful and clear.

What about questions that show no or minimal research effort but are useful?
For example, I upvoted [Is there an indicator like Battery-Status?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/128198/is-there-an-indicator-like-battery-status) because it points to a need to get [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) updated by "community participation".

Comment: It's useful, thus making it upvotable.

Answer (score 1):

To me that just seems like you want to double-upvote the "What Application Indicators are available?". I really can't understand the need to change the tooltip. It is, in my opinion, exactly what is should be.